# keep the aspect ration of main window on tkinter

Tags: tkinter, ttk

Creating an app with tkinter that needs some aspect ratios to work petty well, for that I need to keep the ratio of the main window, but if I bind a  so when the window refreshes it goes into an infinite loop, any way to check this and only really do when someone gives resize in the app?

```py
    def appBinds(self):
        def keepRatio(e):
            width = int(e.width)
            height = int(width/0.75)
            self.geometry(f'{width}x{height}')
            self.unbind('<Configure>')
            print(e)
            
        self.bind('<Configure>', keepRatio)
```

Comment: Try `self.wm_aspect(3, 4, 3, 4)` instead of binding `<Configure>` event.  Note that `wm_aspect()` seems not working in Windows platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the infinite loop issue, you need to call `self.geometry(...)` only when the height is not the expected height as below:

```py
    def appBinds(self):
        def keepRatio(e):
            if e.widget is self:
                height = int(e.width / 0.75)
                if e.height != height:
                    self.geometry(f"{e.width}x{height}")

        self.bind('<Configure>', keepRatio)
```